# Signal R not working after app comes from background in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, signalr, signalr.client

I implemented signal R code from this linkhttps://github.com/edgarleonardo/ChatAppXamarinFormWithWebSocket it is working fine when app launch first time when user press back button and App goes into the background after a user came back again Signal R not working its show status connected but not receive message from signal R.please help me it wastes my 3 days but not getting any solution.

**My signal R initialization code is below**

```
_chatServices = DependencyService.Get<IChatServices>();ChatServices._proxy.On("SendNotifications", (string message) => 
OnMessageReceived(this, new ChatMessage
            {
               Message = message
           }));

           await _chatServices.Connect();

            await _connection.Start();
             _connection.Send("Test");
           await _chatServices.Send("test")
```

Same code i wrote in OnResume() method inside App.xaml signal R connected but message not receiving.

Comment: Probably you might want to close your connection when app goes background then connect and join the chat group again when resumes!
Solution for your problem depends upon how you are managing the instance of your SignalR client connection.

Comment: I closed my signal R connection on OnStop(). Should I make only one instance of signal R for the whole project?

Comment: You should implement some method to check the app state and reconnect to hub when app goes from background to foreground. The connection will always time out when app goes to background.